# Can I use Rock Band Drums with Guitar Hero World Tour on the Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, rock-band, guitar-hero-world-tour

I've picked up some Rock Band drums (cable, 4 drums) and have plugged them into my Wii, but they dont work with Guitar Hero World Tour (it doesn't recognize them).

How can I get them to work?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out all I had to do was plug the drums in, and not touch them at all while the system and game were starting up, then they worked!